# Convert Javascript UTF-8 to ASCII (like Iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string) in PHP)

Tags: javascript, utf-8, ascii, iconv

I'm wondering how it's possible to 'translate' characters in UTF-8 to the closest ASCII equivalent using Javascript, just like Iconv doest in PHP.

Example:

ü becomes u
ó becomes o

I'd rather not use a replace, because a) it requires a complete set of characters, which is a lot of work and b) i'd would be hard to get a complete set of characters, and i'll never be certain if i'm missing one or two.

Comment: When you say "UTF-8", do you *really* mean UTF-8? Like, a string of "characters" whose elements are not actually characters at all, but simply UTF-8 code-units promoted to 16 bits? Or do you mean "Unicode", i.e., a normal JavaScript UTF-16 string?

Comment: It's possible, but there's no algorithmic way to do it besides having a map from Unicode values to whatever ASCII "equivalent" you (or somebody) think to be appropriate. Note that a UTF-8 string may include code points for *many* very different alphabets.

Comment: The term for this is 'transcription' or 'transliteration', there are probably some libraries out there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Pointy said, your only option is to map/replace characters according to a dictionary.

You'll find this really useful: https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/blob/a579796a30e583c4dfa09e0a86e4abd21e0b5b56/plugins/diacritic.js

Comment: Here's more http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/transforms/Latin-ASCII.xml

Comment: Uoah @Esailija ! That's really complete! :)

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but the GitHub link is broken.

Comment: @Jaruba Here you go, mate :) https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/blob/a579796a30e583c4dfa09e0a86e4abd21e0b5b56/plugins/diacritic.js

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way I've found:

```
var str = "üó";
var combining = /[\u0300-\u036F]/g; 

console.log(str.normalize('NFKD').replace(combining, ''));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize

Comment: Only drawback : it is part of EcmaScript 6, and doesn't work on all browsers

Comment: Another drawback: only covers combining marks, not full transliteration.

Comment: Check out similar SO question and accepted answer for comments why the above code won't work - the comments list letters that this code fails to replace:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

There is now a port of iconv to JS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv

```
var iconv = new Iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE');
iconv.convert('ça va が'); // "ca va "
```

Comment: this should become the official answer.